How do I disable system sleep on macbook
I know how to disable sleep by doing
sudo pmset disablesleep 1

And this prevents the system from sleeping when i close the lid.
But this also prevents my macbook from asking password when I close my lid, which leads to security problems...
So, I want my mac to turn off display(which makes my mac ask password) but the system to not sleep when I close the lid.
I also tried Amphetamine but didn't work for me.
